# Remover criação de coluna serial EntityFramework + Npgsql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, migrations

Ola, 
Estou criando uma aplicação utilizando Fluent API + Entityframework. Porém nas minhas classes de domínio ao determinar que uma propriedade é PK ele automaticamente define ela como serial, não gostaria de obter esse comportamento pois ele automaticamente irá criar uma SEQUENCE para cada campo de PK das minhas tabelas. Como eu faço para remover essa validação e definir que quando o campo for chave primaria não quero que seja serial e sim só integer?

Obrigado

Comment: Apesar de ter respondido a pergunta para você (se for a certa, marque como correta), gostaria de saber qual o seu cenário, ou preocupação em não usar IDENTITY ("serial") para suas primary keys. Isso é, normalmente, indicado.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa marcar a coluna para não gerar o sequencial. Isso deve resolver para você:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<*nome_da_entidade*>()
        .Property(m => m.*campo*)
             .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

Outra forma que imagino ser automática seria incluindo o atributo abaixo diretamente na propriedade:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGenerated(
    System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

Ou, melhor, adicione `System.ComponenteModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` às suas cláusulas `using` e fica apenas assim:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```